# Tax coins for Universal Basic Income

Tags: stablecoins

I am working on building a coin that will be useful in providing UBI, but need a method to maintain the price of the coin, so that it doesn't fall below threshold.

Here is the idea:
So every month, each person will be paid 10,000 Dollar-Tax coins.

But dollar tax coins has the special property of disappearing. More time you keep the money, the more will be the transaction cost.
The amount of money lost per time is equal to 10,000/ 24 months in minutes.
An analogy can be the speed, the distance covered is 10,000 and speed will be 10,000/24 months in minutes.

So, if you keep 10,000 dollar-Tax coins a day, you will lose 13.888 (10,000/(24months*30days)) dollar-Tax coins.

After coins are burned, new coins will be minted to pay UBI again.

But how to maintain the price, as their is burning of coin, will the price will rise? How to make sure that the price don't fall below a threshold. Like use some reserve, but don't know how to implement it or start burning more fast when prices goes below threshold. Any ideas and problems with this model are welcome.

Comment: 1) be aware that a token holder can potentionally safe taxes by generating a new address and sends token to that address.
2) I think you should be fine by just safing the fiat/token price in a contract. Is that what you want?

Comment: 1) For new address problem KYC will be done. 2) I don't care if prices go above the fiat/token price, only need make sure it doesn't go below threshold.

Comment: You say: "After coins are burned, new coins will be minted to pay UBI again." That means the amount of token circulating does not change, right? That should mean that the price does not change.

Comment: Yes, the amount of token circulation doesn't change, but price (the exchange rate) can change due to  more or less demand.

Comment: Also, token circulation at any instance may be different, as UBI will be minted in the 1 week of month.

Comment: I am worried the issue of less demand which will decrease the price below the fiat/token price.

Comment: I think you should rethink your idea a bit. Your model needs KYC in a way that each address has to be mapped to a certain user to prevent safing taxes. If this token should be on an exchange it might be impossible for you to track your coins. The exchange would have to your token on every order and report to you. you would have to build your own exchange for that.

Comment: KYC for only giving the UBI, they can't safe taxes because of its property of disappearing which will be coded in smart contract. The account balance is in control of smart contract right, not with exchange.

Comment: buyer can check how many days money is present in the wallet, and how much they will get, for it a web page can be made.

Comment: You have to make sure that it doesn't matter if the user sends token to himself or someone else. Use the block number instead of timestamps! I think the only way to prevent fraud is to use a linear burn amount depending on the block number of the last transaction. But maintaining the price is difficult because your model wants people to get rid of the coins

Comment: I too was thinking now about block number. Yes, the main problem is maintaining the price so that it doesn't fall beyond threshold. I have not thought of any working solution yet. Use reserve but don't know how to. Experts of building stable coin can help here.

Comment: what do you mean by reserve? can you explane that a bit further in your question